# Django get count based on foreign Key for every month

Tags: python, django

I am generating short URL and generating a hash corresponding to it saving it in DB. And for every hash i am also saving some client data. Now i want to get total number of clicks for a given hash for every month

`Like for DCmuih their are 20 clicks in January and 30 in Feb and so on`

```
models.py

import ast
import uuid
import base64
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from qlu.settings import HOST_NAME
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 


class short_url(models.Model):
    """
        This is a short_url class 
    """
    blocked = models.BooleanField(default=False)                                # To check whether URL is blocked or not 
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                            # When URL is updated
    url = models.TextField(validators=[URLValidator()])                         # URL entered by the user
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                        # When URL is created
    url_hash = models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True,db_index=True)        # base64 encoded URL id  

    def _generateShortUrl(self):
        """
            This function will generate base64 encoded URL hash
        """
        hash = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(uuid.uuid1().bytes)[:6]
        hash_exist = short_url.objects.filter(url_hash=hash)
        while hash_exist:
            hash = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(uuid.uuid1().bytes)[:6]
            hash_exist = short_url.objects.filter(url_hash=hash)        
            continue       
        return hash 


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
            Custom Save method for link model 
        """
        self.url_hash = self._generateShortUrl()        
        super(short_url, self).save(*args, **kwargs)    


    def get_short_url(self):
        """
            This method returns the url_hash related to the url 
        """
        return HOST_NAME + self.url_hash


    def __unicode__(self):
        """
            This method convert Django model object to the user readable string 
        """
        return unicode(self.url)


class click_info(models.Model):
    """
        This is a click_info class 
    """
    user_ip = models.TextField()                                                # Store the user_ip
    user_agent = models.TextField()                                             # Store the user_agent
    http_refrer = models.TextField()                                            # Store the http_refrer
    hash = models.ForeignKey(short_url)                                         # base64 encoded URL id
    get_parameters = models.TextField()                                         # Store other get_parameters
    request_time = models.DateTimeField()                                       # When user made the request_time
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                            # When click_info is updated
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                        # When click is created


    def get_parameters_dict(self):
        """
            This method returns the get parameter dict
        """
        return ast.literal_eval(self.get_parameters)


    def __unicode__(self):
        """
            This method convert Django model object to the user readable string 
        """
        return unicode(self.hash)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

class short_url_admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
        short_url_admin class
    """
    list_display = ('url','blocked','updated_at',
                    'created_at','url_hash')
    exclude = ('url_hash',)


class url_info_admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
        url_info_admin class
    """
    list_display = ('user_ip','user_agent','http_refrer',
                    'hash','request_time','get_parameters_dict')    

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
admin.site.register(short_url,short_url_admin)
admin.site.register(click_info,url_info_admin)
```

Comment: To get total number of clicks for every hash `print models.short_url.objects.get(url_hash='DCmuih').click_info_set.count()` But how do i get total number for every month

Comment: Check out `annotations`. But I think this would have to be solved with `extra` or raw queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a query with time range:

```
import datetime
from models import click_info

def get_click_by_month(month, year, hash):
    d1 = datetime.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=1)
    d2 = datetime.datetime(year=year, month=month + 1, day=1)
    clicks = click_info.objects.filter(url_hash=hash, created_at__range=[d1, d2])
    return len(clicks)
```

P.S. PEP8 recommends to use CamelCase to name classes. Of course it's not obligatory but at least people inside the team must use same principles of code writing. Using PEP8 is just easier than creating your own rules.